# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in javafx timeline

Tags: java, exception, javafx, timeline, concurrentmodification

I haven't made Thread myself.
I have one timeline that runs from the beginning to the end of the program which is as follows:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(TIMELINE_DELAY), event -> {
            intrudersList.forEach(Intruder::action);
            towersList.forEach(Tower::action);
            otherActivesList.forEach(Active::action);
        }));
timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

And when the die method of the Intruder class is called, i get this Concurrent Modification Exception.

First, I don't actually understand how timeline works! Does it create new Threads itself or what? and what will happen if for example we have a timeline that does a task every 10 seconds and that task takes 15 seconds to be done!
And second indeed: How can i get this fixed!?

```
public void die() {
    this.getCell().getContent().remove(this);
    TimeLine.getInstance().removeIntruder(this);
    System.out.println("death of intruder at: " + cell);
}
```

Comment: Simply wrap the content of `die` into a Platform.runLater(() -> { ... }) block.

Comment: thanks. then, when will the lambda get invoked exactly?!

Comment: Maybe you are trying to edit a List while you iterate over it? What is `Intruder::action` doing?

Comment: Please post the stack trace. Which line is actually throwing the exception? The `Timeline` does not create any new threads, and the event handler is executed on the (already running) FX Application Thread. There's no reason at all to believe this is a threading issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @DVarga,
This is what the problem was and how i fixed it:
the problem was that I was modifying the `intrudersList` in `removeIntruder` , while iterating on it in `KeyFrame`.
And I solved it by wrapping the body of the `removeIntruder` method in a `Platform.runLater(() -> { ... })` block.
I Guess what Platform.runLater does is that it waits until the list is modifyable and then modifies it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). This exceptions typically happens when a list is modified while that is not allowed.

This can occur when 2 different threads are trying to modify the same list concurrently, but more often it means you are trying to modify a list while iterating over it (which is not allowed).